# Parameter binding and IN operator

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, parameters

I'm pretty convinced it's not possible, but just in case:

How do you bind the right (list) parameter for the `IN` operator?

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz IN ('cow', 'chicken');
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't work:

```
list = ['cow', 'chicken']
db.execute('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz IN ?', list)
```

Parameter binding is not only prettier than direct interpolation of values, but also safer: one of the main reasons to use it is to stop the infamous [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com). However, are you stuck with manual escaping for the IN parameter?

```
list = ['cow', 'chicken']
sqllist = list.map { |el| "'#{SQLite3::Database.quote(el)}'" }.join(',')
db.execute('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz IN (#{sqllist})')
```

(The examples are Ruby with sqlite3 gem, but the question actually applies to all languages/libraries that do parameter binding for you.)

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible; whether you use AR, you might find this link useful: [`ActiveRecord::Sanitization`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array).

Comment: @mudasobwa: Yeah, I figured as much. Naw, my current thing is just a command-line script with SQLite backend, AR is definitely an overkill. Feel free to submit "not possible" as an answer, if you wish, because I was half-convinced it would come down to that, and it actually answers my question; if no-one gives me anything clever in a day or so, I'll accept it.

Comment: Since I have neither proof nor brilliant blah-blah-explanation, I would suggest you to post this yourself and accept your own answer. It’s kinda bona fide :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) gem. It makes working with SQLite very easy, along with migrating to other DBMs when you are ready. In particular, look at the README as it will give  you a jumpstart.

Comment: @theTinMan: I already know about it, but as I already said, I don't need ORM for the project that inspired the question, and it'll never use anything but SQLite. The question is on parameter binding in plain SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL you pass to `db.execute` is just a string and the number of placeholders only needs to match the number of values you hand it. So, you can build the placeholders based on `list.length` and drop them in with string interpolation:

```
placeholders = Array.new(list.length, '?').join(',')
db.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz IN (#{placeholders})", list)
```

This is perfectly safe because you know exactly what's going into `placeholders`.

Comment: Ahhhh, that's smart! :) Thank you.